# How to collect in memory strings of process which executes for a second and terminates

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, malware-detection

How to collect in memory strings of process which executes for a second and terminates in seconds?, if even not able to suspend it to check for in memory strings

I was analyzing one malware file which executed for a second and terminates,not able to check in memory strings

Comment: what if you would single-step the binary under the debugger?

Comment: You might have some luck with flare-floss. 
https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/automatically-extracting-obfuscated-strings
It says it "Extract human-readable strings from memory state difference."